# Rust concatenate &str and i32 into one variable

Tags: rust

Sorry, but I have no idea why I am getting an error when I want to show Error as a result

```
pub fn content<'a>(names: Vec<Option<String>>) -> Result<bool, [&'a str; 3]> {
    let mut count = 0;
    for name in names {
        count = count + 1;
        if name.is_none() {
            let message = format!("Error, position: {}", count);
            return Err(["0", "Error", message.as_str()])
        }
    }
    return Ok(true)
}
```

I'm converting my **message** variable `String` to `&str` and it should be fine, but I'm getting the following error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `message`
 --> src\main.rs:8:20
  |
8 |             return Err(["0", "Error", message.as_str()])
  |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-------^^^^^^^^^^^
  |                    |                  |
  |                    |                  `message` is borrowed here
  |                    returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

It tells me that I cannot return the value of a reference but at the same time I don't know how to solve it. I would like to know with one explanation at a time, if possible.

Comment: `message` is a local variable, so it's going to be deleted at function end. You probably want that field to be a `String`, which is owned by the data structure, and you'll likely want to make a struct for your error type rather than using an array

Comment: If I change my `Result<bool, [& 'a str; 3]>` to `Result<bool, [String; 3]>` if it works for me but I would like it to return the Error result with `&'a str`, and I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: it's generally not possible you may return a `&'static str`

Comment: is there another way to concatenate variables?

Comment: It may be appropriate to use a tuple than a fixed array `(i32, &str, String)` for example. Though, even more appropriate would be to make a struct to better name and encapsulate the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable "message" is a local variable that will disappear after the function call (lifetime issue).
To make it compile, you can just return `Result<bool, [String; 3]>` as well and convert all your str to String.

**Concatenate &str and i32**

Generally, Rust basic types like [i32](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html) already implement Trait [std::string::ToString](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html) and you can call `to_string()` on it directly. Have a look at my proposition():

```
pub fn content<'a>(names: Vec<Option<String>>) -> Result<bool, [String; 3]> {
    let mut count = 0;
    for name in names {
        count = count + 1;
        if name.is_none() {
            let message = format!("Error, position: {}", count);
            return Err(["0".to_string(), "Error".to_string(), message]);
        }
    }
    return Ok(true);
}

fn proposition(names: Vec<Option<String>>) -> Result<bool, [String; 3]> {
    let mut count = 0;
    for name in names {
        count = count + 1;
        if name.is_none() {
            let mut message = "Error, position: ".to_string();
            message += &count.to_string(); // <-- I concat String and i32 here
            return Err(["0".to_string(), "Error".to_string(), message]);
        }
    }
    return Ok(true);
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", content(vec![Some("test".to_string()), None]));
    println!("{:?}", proposition(vec![Some("test".to_string()), None]));
}
```

I get the same results as you expected:

```
Err(["0", "Error", "Error, position: 2"])
Err(["0", "Error", "Error, position: 2"])
```

Comment: well I'll have to change `str` to `String`, thanks for your time.